# ASP.NET MVC renders html tags & attributes in lowercase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

It seems that both Asp.net MVC Core and Asp.net MVC 5.x render html tags & attributes in lowercase and this behavior breaks angular bindings. To give an example: in my `view.cshtml` I define Angular component with camel case binding:

`<my-component [fooBar]="foo"></my-component>`

which is later rendered as:

`<my-component [foobar]="foo"></my-component>`

As far as Angular bindings are case-sensitive, input-property `fooBar` inside component remains `undefined`. Is there any way to override this rendering behavior and render html as-is?

Comment: Silly question but can't you just define your angular stuff in lower-case? (Apologies I'm not an Angular user)

Comment: Because we're currently migrating from old angular 1.x project and there's bunch of props in place named like `isEmptyDefaultStakeAllowed` which honestly look awful when in lower `isemptydefaultstakeallowed`

Comment: What type of tag is my-component?

Comment: mvc(razor) renders something inside `@` to html, if you have html tag's on .cshtml then mvc should behave independent. something you might be missing, is your html with angular tag's kind off dynamic ?

Comment: should have been `is-empty-default-stake-allowed` as W3C suggests all markup be in lower case. Razor is just following the rules.. And Angular is being .. Angular. They should have known better than to be case sensitive on markup.

Answer (score 3):

When I put this in a cshtml file:

`<test-tag [testingThisThing]="123" anotherThingTEST="abc"></test-tag>`

I get exactly the same in the HTML source.  Are you sure that the element isn't being modified after loading?  Are you looking at "View Source" (not "Inspect Element")?

That said, my `test-tag` isn't defined as anything anywhere - are you using Tag Helpers or something?  MVC itself doesn't lowercase all attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at view source, it appears that it is being rendered by razor as written, but when the element actually appears in chrome, it is lower-cased. I can only assume this is a chrome "feature".